# Weird string appears in Sublime text filenames

Tags: sublimetext2, sublimetext

Today when I started my work with Sublime Text I just discovered that a weird string appears in my filenames that is added dynamically by Sublime. It doesn't matter if it's a newly created project or saved file. (I have a paid license, however I don't think it's about that)

This is how it looks like:

[image]

What causes this and is it something I should worried about or not?

Comment: It's unclear from your question, but if you're concerned about the text in `()` in the title, that's the name of the folder/project that's open in the window and isn't part of the file name. Also you tagged the question as `sublimetext3` but the image shows Sublime Text 2.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming that you're opening files on a remote (S)FTP server with FileZilla 3. As pointed out in the comment, the name in brackets is the folder/project name. In this case the folder is a temporary folder created by FileZilla, hence the `fz3-` prefix.